# Erase an encrypted Samsung SSD on a Dell laptop previously used in a business

Tags: laptop, ssd, secure-erase

I recently bought a laptop from a company which was about to close (I promise I'm not a thief).
Its a Dell Latitude which contains an encrypted SSD (samsung 128gb). I can use the laptop with any other hard drive but I don't want to destroy the SSD.

How can I erase EVERYTHING in it, including the encryption?

I really don't want to look at the data, only want to use the SSD. I've tried using Parted Magic erasing tools but still can't install any OS on it, because the installation program doesn't detects it. Also gparted can't draw a new partition table.

PD: I'm using the nwipe tool right now, but it'll take about 30 hours to finish.

Comment: The best solution is just to perform a secure erase on the drive. The way I'd do it is to boot into a Linux live disc and follow [this procedure](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase).

Comment: What is the purpose of doing a secure wipe?  If you simply format the drive, and implement your own encryption, you have made the previous encrypted file unrecoverable.  A quick format should be enough for this task.

Comment: I can't format the drive because it showd an input/output error. Could this be a hardware encryption?

Comment: If you cannot reformat the drive, there is a problem with the drive and it needs to be replaced.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you exactly need/want. The zero fill is probably overkill and puts unnecessary write/erase cycles on the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has a tool called [Samsung Magician](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html).

> The Magician SSD management utility is designed to work with all Samsung SSD products including 470 Series, 750 Series, 830 Series, 840 Series, 850 Series, 950 Series and 960 Series. This software is not compatible with other manufacturers SSDs.

It includes a secure erase feature. It will depend on the exact type of drive you have. You will need to take it out of the laptop and mount it in another PC or laptop. Read the manual first as there are some caveats on what it can or can not do.

Comment: I also used magician tools, but this ssd is not compatible with them. :(

Comment: Contact Dell support then. They may have a tool you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old thread, but I've just tested solution via PSID revert from Drive Trust Alliance.

Description is here: https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/PSID-Revert

Just download their recovery image, burn it on USB drive. Boot that drive in legacy mode and login as root with no password. Next steps are described in the link.

Just remember, you need 32 char code that has to be physicaly on top of the drive, so you have to open notebook or PC and write down that PSID code from the sticker!

I've tested many ways to remove SED from SSD drive, but this one only worked on my Samsung EVO 860 SSD.